# Is Parse.initialize() asynchronous?

Tags: android, parse-platform

Is Parse.initialize() a fire-and-forget asynchronous method?

Consider the following code:

Application class:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {


        super.onCreate();

        // Initialize Crash Reporting.
        ParseCrashReporting.enable(this);

        // Enable Local Datastore.
        Parse.enableLocalDatastore(this);

        // Add your initialization code here
        Parse.initialize(this);

        ParseACL defaultACL = new ParseACL();
        // Optionally enable public read access.
        // defaultACL.setPublicReadAccess(true);
        ParseACL.setDefaultACL(defaultACL, true);
    }
}
```

Test case:

```
import android.test.AndroidTestCase;

import com.parse.DeleteCallback;
import com.parse.LogInCallback;
import com.parse.ParseException;
import com.parse.ParseObject;
import com.parse.ParseUser;
import com.parse.SaveCallback;
import com.parse.SignUpCallback;

import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;

/**
 * Created by alex on 31/03/15.
 */
public class UserTest extends AndroidTestCase {

    public UserTest() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    protected void setUp() {

    }

    interface SignupAndLoginCallback {
        public void done(ParseUser user, ParseException e);
    }

    public void signupAndLogin(final SignupAndLoginCallback callback) {

        ParseUser user = new ParseUser();
        user.setUsername("olatest2");
        user.setPassword("kari4ever");
        user.setEmail("olatest2@nordmann.no");

        user.put("phone", "650-253-0000");

        user.signUpInBackground(new SignUpCallback() {
            public void done(ParseException e) {
                ParseUser.logInInBackground("olatest2", "kari4ever", new LogInCallback() {
                    public void done(ParseUser user, ParseException e) {
                        callback.done(user, e);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }


   public void testSignupLoginDestroy() throws InterruptedException {

       try {
           Thread.sleep(1000);
       } catch (InterruptedException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }

        ParseUser user = new ParseUser();
        user.setUsername("olatest");
        user.setPassword("kari4ever");
        user.setEmail("olatest@nordmann.no");

        user.put("phone", "650-253-0000");

        final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);

        class Spy {
            ParseUser user;
            ParseException signupException;
            ParseException loginException;
            ParseException deleteException;
        }

        final Spy spy = new Spy();

        user.signUpInBackground(new SignUpCallback() {
            public void done(ParseException e) {
                spy.signupException = e;
                ParseUser.logInInBackground("olatest", "kari4ever", new LogInCallback() {
                    public void done(ParseUser user, ParseException e) {
                        spy.loginException = e;
                        spy.user = user;

                        if (user == null || e != null) {
                           latch.countDown();
                        } else {
                            user.deleteEventually(new DeleteCallback() {
                                @Override
                                public void done(ParseException e) {
                                    spy.deleteException = e;
                                    latch.countDown();
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    }
                });

            }
        });

        latch.await(); 

        assertNull(spy.signupException);
        assertNull(spy.loginException);
        assertNull(spy.deleteException);
        assertNotNull(spy.user);
    }


    public void testCreateObject() throws InterruptedException {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);

        class Spy {
            ParseException loginException;
            ParseException deleteException;
            ParseException saveException;
            ParseUser user;
        }

        final Spy spy = new Spy();


        signupAndLogin(new SignupAndLoginCallback() {
            @Override
            public void done(ParseUser user, ParseException e) {
                spy.loginException = e;
                spy.user = user;

                if (e == null && user != null) {
                    ParseObject gameScore = new ParseObject("GameScore");
                    gameScore.put("score", 1337);
                    gameScore.put("playerName", "Sean Plott");
                    gameScore.put("cheatMode", false);
                    gameScore.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void done(ParseException e) {
                            spy.saveException = e;
                            latch.countDown();
                        }
                    });
                } else {
                    latch.countDown();
                }
            }
        });


        latch.await();
        assertNull(spy.loginException);
        assertNull(spy.deleteException);
        assertNull(spy.saveException);
        assertNotNull(spy.user);
    }

}
```

If the `Thread.sleep(1000);` calls are removed from the test cases sometimes the tests blow up with an exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You must register this ParseObject subclass before instantiating it.
at com.parse.ParseObject.<init>(ParseObject.java:166)
at com.parse.ParseObject.<init>(ParseObject.java:127)
at com.parse.ParseUser.<init>(ParseUser.java:89)
at agens.no.gjensidigeparseandroidclient.UserTest.signupAndLogin(UserTest.java:35)
at agens.no.gjensidigeparseandroidclient.UserTest.testCreateObject(UserTest.java:122)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:191)
at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:176)
at android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner.onStart(InstrumentationTestRunner.java:554)
at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1701)
```

I suspect this is because the code the registers the `ParseUser` has not been run.

If so, could Parse add a callback to `Parse.initialize()`?

Answer (score -1):

This is NOT asynchronous method. You should add your keys to Parse.initialize()! The tutorial example is misleading!

Parse.initialize(this, "id","key");

https://www.parse.com/apps/quickstart#parse_data/mobile/android/native/new

Comment: The keys are added in `AndroidManifest.xml` using `<meta-data>` tags. This is another supported way to set the id and the key, it works fine. If `Parse.initialize()` is not fire-and-forget asynchronous, how do you explain `IllegalArgumentException` if you attempt to use the `Parse` object directly after calling `initialize()`? It works fine if the test case thread sleeps for a few hundred microseconds.  I suspect `Parse.initialize()` kicks of an asynchronous task for which there is no callback.

Comment: I am not familiar with test cases, but where do you initialize Parse in the test code?

Comment: Parse is initialised by MyApplication which is newwed up by the test framework prior to running the tests